# Is my login function secure ? how to improve it?

Tags: php, optimization, object-oriented

Using cakePHP, I would love to have your point of view about this large source code, i am not sure if its enought secure. `sha1()` will be removed with another script. 
I found this large script can be optimized but how ?

i have many times

```
$this->Session->setFlash("You hav to complete each fiedls", "error");
```

and

```
$this->Request->redirect(SITE . "users/account");
```

I wonder if I can optmize this also:

```
class UsersController extends Controller {
    function account($Req){
        if(isset($Req->post->login)){
            $login = addslashes($Req->post->login);
            $password = sha1(addslashes($Req->post->password));
            $pass_confirm = sha1(addslashes($Req->post->pass_confirm));
            $email = addslashes($Req->post->email);
            $signature = addslashes($Req->post->signature);

            if(empty($login) || empty($email)){
                $this->Session->setFlash("You hav to complete each fiedls", "error");
                $this->Request->redirect(SITE . "users/account");
            }
            elseif($pass_confirm != $password) {
                $this->Session->setFlash("You gave two differents password", "error");
                $Req->redirect(SITE . "users/account");
            }

            $this->loadModel("Users");

            $dispoLogin = $this->Users->findCount(array(
                "login" => $login
            ));
            if($dispoLogin === 0){
                $this->Session->setFlash("The login is already use by someone else", "error");
                $this->Request->redirect(SITE . "users/account");
            }

            $dispoEmail = $this->Users->findCount(array(
                "email" => $email
            ));
            if($dispoEmail === 0){
                $this->Session->setFlash("Email adress already use by someone else", "error");
                $this->Request->redirect(SITE . "users/account");
            }

            if(empty($password)){
                $q = $this->Users->findFirst(array(
                    "fields" => "password",
                    "conditions" => array(
                        "id" => $this->User->id
                    )
                ));
                $password = sha1($q->password);
            }

            $this->Users->save(array(
                "id" => $this->User->id,
                "login" => $login,
                "password" => $password,
                "email" => $email,
                "signature" => $signature
            )); 
            $this->user->setData(array(
                "login" => $login,
                "password" => $password,
                "email" => $email,
                "signature" => $signature
            ));

            $this->Session->setFlash("Your profile page is updated");
            $this->Request->redirect(SITE);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answered you on SO but I'll repeat it here too.

Please read the [CakePHP Documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/), preferably from the start because you really are getting a lot wrong here.

- There is no need to `addslashes()` everything, (or anything ever)
- CakePHP has it's own [AuthComponent](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1250/Authentication), so no need to roll your own
- It also has a [validation engine](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1143/Data-Validation), so no need to validate anything here
- You're also passing some Request object to the method? I don't even want to ask...

This action should basically be about 6 lines long. TL;DR: Read the CakePHP Authentication docs, and start again.

Comment: Thank you for your answer
i really see i have a lake on my knowledge. I'll fix that